# Somar campos MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o código abaixo em que necessito somar o valor de uma coluna (MySQL) e o resultado desta soma, subtrair por um valor qualquer, exemplo: `5000` e o resultado desta operação ser passado para a página PHP.

Meu código:

```
<?php

$opcoes2 = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
$conexao2 = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVER."; dbname=".DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD,          $opcoes2);

$sql2  = "SELECT SUM(valor_boleto) - 5000 FROM boleto";
$stm2 = $conexao2->prepare($sql2);
$stm2->execute();

while($row2 = $stm2->fetch())  {
$soma = $row2['sum(valor_boleto)'];
 }  

?>
```

### HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
   A Soma dos Números do Banco de Dados foi <?=$soma?>.

    <div id="chart_div"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

O erro gerado é:

> Notice: Undefined index: sum(valor_boleto) in C:\xampp\htdocs\grafico\grafico.php on line 77

O `select` está OK, pois via *console* retorna o valor certinho.

Se minha coluna "`valor_boleto`" existir 3 campos de `5000`, somaria-se `15000` e subtraindo por `5000`, deveria retornar um "`echo`" de `10000`.

Grato quem puder ajudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agrupa a operação e da um alias que resolve.

```
SELECT (SUM(valor_boleto)-5000) AS total FROM boleto
```

Ai la no php pega o total assim:

```
$soma = $row2['total'];
```

Comment: Tiro certeiro hein ??? Funcionou! Obrigado Neuber, abraços.